# Outlook Plugin upload FileReference as attachment

Tags: javascript, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, yo

I am developing an outlook plugin that needs to upload not a file attachment but a reference file when the user compose a message.

I've tried to use these 3 methods :

1. addFileAttachmentAsync(uri, attachmentName, [options],
   [callback])
2. addItemAttachmentAsync(itemId, attachmentName,
   [options], [callback])
3. makeEwsRequestAsync(data, callback, [userContext])

Results of the 3 methods :

1. Not able to add referenceFile
2. MessageText":"You cannot attach yourself.","ResponseCode":"ErrorCannotAttachSelf","ResponseClass":"Error"}]}}}
3. HTTP 500 error.

Code of the second method :

```
var messageId = await getMessageItemId();
var exchangeAttachment = await uploadAttachmentToExchange(accessToken, messageId, attachment.name,fileUploaded.webUrl);
await addReferenceAttachment(exchangeAttachment.id, attachment.name);

var uploadAttachmentToExchange = async function(accessToken, messageId, fileName, fileUrl){
    var OneDriveURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/"+messageId+"/attachments";
    var payload = JSON.stringify({ 
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.referenceAttachment", 
        "name": fileName, 
        "sourceUrl": fileUrl, 
        "providerType": "oneDriveBusiness", 
        "permission": "organizationEdit",
        "isFolder" : false,
        "isInline" : false
    }) ;
    
    return new Promise((successCallback, failureCallback) => {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ accessToken
            },
            url: OneDriveURL,
            data : payload
        })
        .done(function( response ) {
            successCallback(response);
        })
        .fail(function(resultat, status, error) {
            failureCallback(resultat);
        });
    }); 
};

var getMessageItemId = async function(){
    return new Promise((successCallback, failureCallback) => {
        mailboxItem.getItemIdAsync(function(asyncResult){
            if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                failureCallback(asyncResult.error.message);
            } else {
                successCallback(asyncResult.value);
            }
        });
    });  
};

var addReferenceAttachment = async function(itemId, attachmentName){
    return new Promise((successCallback, failureCallback) => {
        mailboxItem.addItemAttachmentAsync(itemId, attachmentName, {}, function(asyncResult){
            if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                failureCallback(asyncResult.error.message);
            } else {
                successCallback(asyncResult);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Code of the third method :

```
var messageId = await getMessageItemId();
await uploadAttachmentUsingEWSAPI(messageId);

var uploadAttachmentUsingEWSAPI = async function (messageId){
    var request = 
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"'+
    '               xmlns:m="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"'+
    '               xmlns:t="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"'+
    '               xmlns:soap="https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'
    '  <soap:Header>'
    '    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1" />'
    '    <t:TimeZoneContext>'
    '      <t:TimeZoneDefinition Id="Central Standard Time" />'
    '    </t:TimeZoneContext>'
    '  </soap:Header>'
    '  <soap:Body>'
    '    <m:CreateAttachment>'
    '      <m:ParentItemId Id="'+ messageId +'" />'
    '      <m:Attachments>'
    '        <t:FileAttachment>'
    '          <t:Name>FileAttachment.txt</t:Name>'
    '          <t:Content>VGhpcyBpcyBhIGZpbGUgYXR0YWNobWVudC4=</t:Content>'
    '        </t:FileAttachment>'
    '      </m:Attachments>'
    '    </m:CreateAttachment>'
    '  </soap:Body>'
    '</soap:Envelope>';

    console.log(request);
    return sendEWSRequest(request);
};

var sendEWSRequest = async function(request){
    return new Promise((successCallback, failureCallback) => {
        Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(request, function(asyncResult){
            if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                failureCallback(asyncResult.error.message);
            } else {
                successCallback(asyncResult);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

None of the three methods works.
Is there a way to upload a cloud attachment like this one ? :

[image]

If yes, what is the method to use ?

Regards

Comment: I can see in option 2 you are trying to attach an Item. Do you need to add an existing Item as an attachment or any file with URL? If you want to attach just an item. You can use of addItemAttachmentAsync and just pass itemId of the mail you want to attach. As the error for Option 2 seems self explanatory that you cannot attach same Item as attachment to itself.

Comment: Hi MSFT team, I've tried to add a reference attachment following this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/api/message-post-attachments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http
The messageId query parameter has been taken from getItemIdAsync method.
Inside the response of the graph api I am getting an ItemId.
I then try to add the reference attachment recently uploaded inside my email composition using addItemAttachmentAsync. 
I receive the MessageText":"You cannot attach yourself.","ResponseCode":"ErrorCannotAttachSelf","ResponseClass":"Error"}]}}}
Please help me !

Comment: In option 2, are you getting the item id? Is the upload on one drive successful?

Comment: Hi MSFT, 
Message ID using getItemIdAsync : AAMkAGIzOTVkOTA4LTJhNDQtNGY1Mi04NTE4LWM4NzU1ZjUyM2NlNwBGAAAAAABqkzyAjfNKRYT58Lg54wwJBwBss1IsJa4vTZLtv7ov94yXAAAAAAEPAABss1IsJa4vTZLtv7ov94yXAAAhHyluAAA=

Item ID I get after uploading the item to exchange : {@odata.context: "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('…vTZLtv7ov94yXAAAhHyluAAA%3D')/attachments/$entity", @odata.type: "#microsoft.graph.referenceAttachment", id: "AAMkAGIzOTVkOTA4LTJhNDQtNGY1Mi04NTE4LWM4NzU1ZjUyM2…tv7ov94yXAAAhHyluAAABEgAQAByeUANApsBOlUyOnk6VcYE="

Comment: Option 2 fails because "addItemAttachmentAsync" API can only add exchange items (email, calendar, or contact item). 
The ItemId you're providing is for OneDrive.

Comment: You can try uploading the files to some blob/server, from where it can be attached to the mail as suggested here : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-and-remove-attachments-to-an-item-in-a-compose-form

Comment: Hi MSFT. I don't want to use : Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync(
            `https://webserver/picture.png`)
because it will attach the file as if it was a normal attachment. 
I would like instead to attach it as if it was a cloud attachment (see the picture in my original post). Is there a way to do it using the Javascript API ?

Comment: The string concatenation `+` is missing in the 3rd method for `request`.

Comment: As a workaround, Could you try adding attachment as a link in the message body using Body APIs. Documentation available here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=outlook-js-preview#setAsync_data__options__callback_

Comment: Hi MSFT, In terms of user experience this is not what I would like for my plugin users.
The problem of this method is that they will not be able to look for messages having attachments. Is there a planned date for being able to handle cloud attachment using Office JS API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the feature: Adding cloud attachment as reference using Addins APIs, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.